# I am trying to write a program to a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here's what I have.

```
"""

Author: Michael Wellman (wellmanm)
Title: pa10.py
Description: Deciphering a document using pennymath.

"""

def decode(inputfile,outputfile):
    **inputfile = open("superDuperTopSecretStudyGuide.txt","rU").read()
    outputfile = open("translatedguide.txt","w")**
    count = 0
    aList = []
    for words in inputfile:
        aList.append(words)
        charCount = len(aList)
        **outpufile.write(aList)**
        while count<charCount:
            print aList[count],
            if (aList[count].isalpha()):            
               if (ord(aList[count])>90):           
                   count = count + ord(aList[count])-95     
               else:                                
                   count = count + ord(aList[count])-63     
            else:
                if (aList[count].isdigit()):       
                   count = count + ord(aList[count])-46             
                else:
                   count = count + 6                        
    **inputfile.close()
    outputfile.close()**
```

The txt files are from my professor :P

The parts bolded are the most important, I believe.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you asking for general feedback or do you have an issue you're trying to fix?  If you want general feedback, the [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site would be a better fit for this type of question.

Comment: The only question you ask is "Any thoughts?", to which I'm sure the majority of respondents here would answer "Yes".  But if you have an actual question some aspect of this program, please ask it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried running the code?

I think if you would you'd get an error message about the line

```
outpufile.write(aList)
```

See, the doc string for `file.write()` method clearly states:

> write(str) -> None.  Write string str to file.
>
> Note that due to buffering, flush() or close() may be needed before
>   the file on disk reflects the data written.

You are supplying it a `list` instead of a `str`. Try changing it to

```
outpufile.write(''.join(aList))
```

or

```
outputfile.write(aList[-1])
```

or whatever fits your needs. Also, you never clear the list, so, as you iterate over `inputfile`, you'll write the first character, then the first and the second, then the first three, etc. Is that intended?

Lastly, you are trying to close `inputfile` which is actually a `str`, not a file, because `file.read()` method returns a `str`.

P.S. Please, never call your variable `inputfile` if it's a string and `words` if it's a single character. That will never help anyone.

Comment: It seems to me that 'words' is a single character, so each element of aList is, too; since inputfile is a string. My thoughts are that the code probably doesn't do what it was intended to do, but we don't know what that is.

Comment: Oh, yes, you're right. The code is really misleading. I'll edit the answer a little.